# Ubuntu 17.10 starts with Nvidia default

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm trying to run my `nvidia` with `bumblebee`, I did it before on older version of Ubuntu. In 17.10 `nvidia-387 and bumblebee` installation was success but instead of `optirun` whole `X` starts using `nvidia`.

There is a `xorg.conf` file in `/etc/X11/` and I deleted it couple of times. But it creates automatically after reboot. `optirun` is working too but I don't think it's necessary when whole `X` is running on `nvidia driver`.

My question is how to prevent system to use `nvidia for X`? I want to run specific application using `optirun` and other should use `intel`. I'm also using `ligthdm instead of gdm` which doesn't start crash with `nvidia`.

I also added `nvidia-387` in `bumblebee black list`.

Comment: Perhaps you need Prime instead and then select the profile at Nvidia X Server Settings?

Comment: I tried nvidia-prime. If I switch to intel, lightdm doesn't load but black screen. Only way to use intel is uninstall the nvidia-driver